# Nested_form has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models dog and litter_field:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_one :litter_field
accepts_nested_attributes_for :litter_field

attr_accessible :litter_field_attributes

end

class LitterField < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :dog

attr_accessible :breed_type

end
```

In my controller I have:

```
class DogsController < ApplicationController

def edit
@dog = Dog.find(params[:id])
@dog.build_litter_field
end
```

And in my view I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for @dog do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :litter_field do |l| %>      
  <div>
      <%= l.label :breed_type %>
      <%= l.input_field :breed_type %>
  </div>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Save" %> 
  <% end %>
```

I've looked at the documentation and from what I can tell this should work, however this page is not on the main edit page which I'm assuming is where the problem lies.  Should I be adding what's in the edit action to a new action which displays the litter_field edit form?

EDIT:

What I am trying to do is split the edit form into separate pages, I've done this by adding additional actions that render extra pages so a user would go to dogs/settings/litter for example to see the litter_field nested form.  I've tried adding @dog.build_litter_field to the litter action which displays the fields but when I try and save the form I am getting the error:

```
Failed to remove the existing associated litter_field. The record failed to save when after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

EDIT 2:

Fixed the above with adding:

```
has_one :litter_field, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :litter_field, update_only: true
```

To dog.rb, the only problem I have now is it won't display the saved value on edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `@dog.build_litter_field` in the `edit` action, it will build a new LitterField overtop of whatever had been saved previously.  I would suggest trying something like this to see if it solves the problem you are currently seeing:

```
def edit
  @dog = Dog.find(params[:id])
  @dog.build_litter_field if @dog.litter_field.nil?
end
```

It can also help to checkout the `debugger` gem.  You can use that to step through controller actions and see what the objects look like after each statement.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution didn't work, I think I'll just put everything in the one table for now until I've learned more to solve this problem.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what did you see?  After you saved the data on your nested could you see the dog and litter_field info in your database?  When you go back in the edit form can you see any dog or litter_field data?